# Geometric mean of precision and recall

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, classification, metrics

I am trying to make a custom metric to evaluate a ML model. I want to make the Weighted geometric mean of precision and recall and weigh it in a way that prioritizes recall over precision. I know that the geometric mean is the sqrt(precision * recall) but I'm not sure how to parametererize it to give more importance to recall in python. There is this metric from imbalance library but I don't see any weights that I can Provide

```
imblearn.metrics.geometric_mean_score(y_true, y_pred, labels=None, pos_label=1, average='multiclass', sample_weight=None, correction=0.0)
```

Any idea on how to implement what I want in python?

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing a `class-imbalance` issue, a `multi-class geometric mean` between precision and recall, weighted by label `supports` (number of position samples for each label) is a great option (this is allowed in imblearn API that you have linked, with parameter `average='weighted'`).

**However, IIUC, is not what you are looking for. You are trying to take a [weighted geometric mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_geometric_mean) between `precision` and `recall`.**

I couldn't find any implementations for weighted geometric mean in popular libraries so I wrote a custom function for this.

You can calculate `precision` and `recall` using the sklearn api from `y_true` and `y_pred` and then use the function to calculate the `weighted geometric mean`.

I have written the `weighted_geometric_mean` function based on the following [definition](https://www.spec.org/gwpg/pastissues/Feb98/opc.static/geometric_mean.html) (the first form with powers instead of exponentials) -

[image]

```
from sklearn.metrics import precision_score, recall_score

y_true = [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]
y_pred = [0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1]

precision = precision_score(y_true, y_pred, average='micro')
recall = recall_score(y_true, y_pred, average='micro')
#parameter 'micro' calculates metrics globally by counting the total TP, FN and FP

scores = [precision, recall]
weights = [0.6,0.4]  #60% precision, 40% recall

def weighted_geometric_mean(scores, weights):
    wgm = np.product(np.power(scores, weights))
    return wgm

weighted_geometric_mean(scores, weights)
```

```
0.3333333333333333
```

The above implementation uses global precision and recall with the parameter `micro`. If you want to consider class-wise weights to calculate precision and recall (for class imbalance situations), please set it to `weighted`

---

**Edit:** On a side note, weighted geometric average between global precision and recall with weights that sum up to 1 (60:40 or 50:50 etc) will always result in the same final value! You can derive this by writing precision in its TP, FP form, and same for Recall. I would therefore recommend label support `weighted` precision and recall.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. The only thing I don't get is where in the function above each of the weights correspond to either precision or recall(i.e. How do we know that 3 is the weight of recall and 2 the weight of precision?)

Comment: I have updated the code to simplfy the definition. Now you can consider the weights to be percentages (0.3 = 30%)

Comment: Check [this link](https://www.spec.org/gwpg/pastissues/Feb98/opc.static/geometric_mean.html) for more details on how to define weights. I have added this as part of the answer too.

Comment: Let me know if this solved your question. thanks!

Comment: Either I don't understand your Edit claim "weighted geometric average between global precision and recall with weights that sum up to 1 (60:40 or 50:50 etc) will always result in the same final value!" or I don't see how that can be true. Are you saying that the choice of weighting has no impact on the outcome?